# Preserve input with LINQ expression using Except instead of Where

Tags: .net, linq, c#-3.0

Given this LINQ expression:

```
items.Select( i => i.ToLowerInvariant() ).Except( keywords )
```

Is there a way to express that where you preserve the casing of the input, without using a Where()?

The Where approach:

```
items.Where( i => !keywords.Contains( i.ToLowerInvariant() ) )
```

I like the way the Except approach reads, but I don't want the altered output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [overload of `Except` that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx). In this case you don't need to roll your own comparer: the built-in `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` class does exactly what you need:

```
items.Except(keywords, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an overload to Except() which takes an IEqualityComparer - you can use on of the built-in string comparers:

```
items.Except( keywords, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase );
```

Comment: You can use the built-in StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.